# findByIdAndUpdate Don't Work Mongoose MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, findby

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PO2C0.png)

I try to update the data in MongoDB Compass via Nodejs in the picture by using findByIdAndpUpdate.

Below is the code that I wanna to update name, price, description with the same _id:

```
router.post('/update',(req,res)=>{
    //new data from edit form
    const update_id = req.body.update_id
    let doc = {
        name: req.body.name,
        price: req.body.price,
        description: req.body.description
    }
    console.log("New data from form :", doc)
    console.log("ID :", update_id)
    Product.findByIdAndUpdate(update_id,doc,{useFindAndModify:false})
    res.redirect('/manage')
})
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRbPx.png)

This is what happened when I run the code in VSCode. Nothing seem to happens in MongoDB compass.

Everything still the same even I sent the update data in my new form to MongoDB compass see in picture.

Comment: Hi, the use of images for code/errors causes many problems. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mongoose [findByIdAndUpdate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.findByIdAndUpdate()) method is an asynchronous task. This means it returns a Promise that you need to either chain a [then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) block to and wait for the task to complete or adopt the [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) pattern.

A simple fix to get your code working would be to use the latter like so:

```js
router.post('/update', async (req,res)=>{ //< Mark callback function as async
   try{
      //new data from edit form
      const update_id = req.body.update_id
      let doc = {
        name: req.body.name,
        price: req.body.price,
        description: req.body.description
      }
      console.log("New data from form :", doc)
      console.log("ID :", update_id)
      const updatedDoc = await Product.findByIdAndUpdate(update_id, doc, {new:true}); //< Use of await and assign return value to variable 
      res.redirect('/manage')
   }catch(err){
      console.log(err);
      //Handle error
   }
});
```

You will notice I have included the option `{new:true}` in the `findByIdAndUpdate`. This tells mongoose to return the updated document i.e it has the changes applied. I have not included the `{useFindAndModify:false}` as this option is only required if using with older versions of mongoose such as V5.x. See [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/5.x/docs/deprecations.html#findandmodify) further details. If you are using an old version of mongoose I would encourage you to please update to V7.x but if your organisation can't then you can of course add the option back in.

Comment: Hi jQueeny, thank you for your advise. I've tried your code and it's look fine in VScode, However the new data didn't update in the MongoDB Compass.

Comment: @CalvinLiang if you do a `console.log(updatedDoc);` directly after the `findByIdAndUpdate()` what does it show? Sometimes you need to hit the refresh button in Compass to see the changes.

Comment: I just did console and it shown:
'Run port 8080
653a761e7e9557d942ea8d75
New data from form : {
  name: 'iPhone 15 Pro Max Ultra',
  price: '1299',
  description: 'A18 Pro'
}
ID :  653a761e7e9557d942ea8d75`. Also refresh in Compass, it still remain the same in Compass even though my add/delete function work fine.

Comment: So `console.log(updatedDoc);` didn't show anything? Do `console.log('updatedDoc = ', updatedDoc);` just to be sure. That will at least show something in the console.

Comment: It shown a lot of messages though. Compass still didn't work (no updated) since data in Terminal got already updated. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77382578/22578081

Comment: @CalvinLiang what you posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77382578/21972629) is the Mongoose Query Object. This is what mongoose creates before it executes the actual update. You would only see this in the console when you logged `console.log('updatedDoc = ', updatedDoc);` if you didn't `await` the execution.  Have you definitely marked your route callback as `async` and and added `await` to the  `findByIdAndUpdate`?

Answer (score -1):

I modified [jQueeny's working solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77378030/findbyidandupdate-dont-work-mongoose-mongodb/77378593#77378593) to this, which also works:

```
router.post('/update',(req,res)=>{
const updateid = req.body.updateid
let data = {
    name:req.body.name,
    price:req.body.price,
    description:req.body.description
}
Product.findByIdAndUpdate(updateid,data)
.then((data)=>{
    res.redirect('manage')
    console.log("New data from form :", data)
    console.log(updateid)
}).catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err);
    res.redirect('manage');
})    })
```

Comment: What did you modify, and why? Is it an improvement? Please add detail/an explanation to your answer when providing a block of code. Code-only answers are rarely useful to readers.